# SQL Server : Text Search Pattern for Performance

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a requirement in which I periodically have to check 40k names against table of 70k names (on Azure SQL Server).

Table has 2 relevant columns

```
FIRSTNAME (nvarchar(15)) 
LASTNAME (nvarchar(20))
```

Name matches must be exact first and last name match.

Naively, my first approach would be to run 40k `select/where firstname='xxx' and lastname='yyy'` queries, but I have to believe there is a more performant way of doing it.  I guess, on the surface, it sounds like about 280k text-based queries.  Obviously, the column is short enough to where I can index it, but surely there is something more I could do?

My first question is, what's the most efficient way to handle a problem like this in SQL Server?

My second question is, does anyone with experience with something like this have any idea of how long a 40k text searches across 70k rows query would take, even just on order of magnitude?  I.e. am I looking at minutes, hours, days, etc?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Where do the 40k names come from? Could you insert them in a temp table (or bulk import)? Then a join/left join or something like this could be possible?

Comment: The 40k names come from a different table (i.e. the user table).

Comment: Then why don't you just join the two tables? select * from tableA a join TableB b on b.FirstName=a.FirstName and b.LastName=a.LastName

Comment: It seems unnecessary to optimize a query with so little data. You should make sure there's an index including both fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index which contains both FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME columns should be enough, if possible, make it clustered.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [idx_yourTable] ON yourTable (
    FIRSTNAME ASC,
    LASTNAME ASC
)
```

If you are not able to create an index on your table, then you can retrive all the data to a temp table and make an index on the temp table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #T_Local
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #T_Azure

SELECT
        ID
--  A seperator is used to avoid case like 
--  'FirstName' + 'LastName' = 'FirstNameLast' + 'Name' 
       ,FIRSTNAME + '|' + LASTNAME AS [FULL_NAME]
       ,FIRSTNAME
       ,LASTNAME
    INTO #T_Local
    FROM server1.DB1.dbo.YourTable

SELECT
        ID
       ,FIRSTNAME + '|' + LASTNAME AS [FULL_NAME]
       ,FIRSTNAME
       ,LASTNAME
    INTO #T_Azure
    FROM server2.DB1.dbo.YourTable

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [idx_t_local] ON #T_Local (
[FULL_NAME] ASC)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [idx_t_azure] ON #T_Azure (
[FULL_NAME] ASC)

SELECT
        tl.ID        AS [ID_Local]
       ,tl.FIRSTNAME AS [FIRSTNAME_Local]
       ,tl.LASTNAME  AS [LASTNAME_Local]
       ,ta.ID        AS [ID_Azure]
       ,ta.FIRSTNAME AS [FIRSTNAME_Azure]
       ,ta.LASTNAME  AS [FIRSTNAME_Azure]
    FROM #T_Local tl
    INNER JOIN #T_Azure ta
        ON tl.FULL_NAME = ta.FULL_NAME
```

At last, 40k to 70k records are not that much data to cause any performance issues even without a proper index.